# Purchasing Points of Interest data in USA?

Tags: data, united-states

I have thousands of POIs with addresses and they are geocoded.  The lat longs are on the road.

I have Tele Atlas POI data, but it also shows the locations closer to the road.

Is there any company which sells POI data (for the USA) and the exact location(lat long) on the ground?

Comment: You are looking for the equivalent of http://www.dmtispatial.com/ for the USA. Good luck on your hunt, I am sorry I can't help you any further.

Comment: try search with these keywords : navigation,GPS,company. you can use keyword such navteq .

Comment: It's worth mentioning that "exact location" is somewhat a matter of interpretation (front door of building? driveway? etc.) -- but I take your point that having it somewhere where that building is, rather than on a road line, can be unhelpful in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Navteq sell these data.

Their HERE product.

http://here.com/business/?lang=en-US

Actually it is most often a lease.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to actually own a bunch of POI data, or are you just looking for a better positioned geocode? Nokia's Here (Same Here mentioned in the other answer, but it's no longer called Navteq at all) offers a geocoder that will (I believe) match against point addressing where available which will be better positioned than just a street address range lookup. I believe they even have a free plan for lower volumes.

https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/introduction.html
https://developer.here.com/get-started#/10134035

Answer (score 0):

Since this popped up again, I thought I would add another avenue.  Depending on the use of these POIs, you may find it useful to pull them from OpenStreetMap.  For those looking for the open alternative, I suggest checking out [this discussion post](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/15/getting-point-of-interest-data-from-openstreetmap) and the [points of interest wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Points_of_interest) from OSM.

Another alternative would be [Google Places](https://developers.google.com/places/) for an API.  I didn't dig too deep into their terms of service/plans to see if there is a free tier similar to their geocoding (2500/daily).

The last option I am thinking of would be using either [ESRI's ArcGIS Online](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=305f2e55e67f4389bef269669fc2e284) or [JS API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/locator_poi.html) to search for points of interest or using the [StreetMap Premium for ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/data/streetmap)

These are other alternatives since the current answers just point to HERE.